# Accessing memory for iterating through an array in-line

Tags: c++

I want to access elements within arrays by traversing their memory locations. Since elements of any given array are stored sequentially, I'm using the `++` operator to increment through their memory locations.
I can write some code like this:

```
    int someArray[4];
    someArray[0] = 44;
    someArray[1] = 55;
    someArray[2] = 66;
    someArray[3] = 77;

    int *location = someArray;
    cout << *++location << endl; // OUTPUT: 55
    cout << *++location << endl; // OUTPUT: 66
```

However I receive errors when I try any of the following:

```
    cout << *(++someArray) << endl;
    // error: lvalue required as increment operand cout << *(++someArray) << endl;

    // OR

    cout << *++&someArray << endl;
    // error: lvalue required as increment operand cout << *++&someArray << endl;

    // OR

    cout << *++(&someArray) << endl;
    // error: lvalue required as increment operand cout << *++(&someArray) << endl;
```

I'm quite new to c++ but from my understanding prefixing a variable with `&` would retrieve its memory location.
Arrays, however, would return their memory location without the `&`.
Whether I use `&` or not I receive errors. 
I'm wanting to increment through the array in-line, however I have to declare a variable, within which the location is stored first.

I'm hoping for some clarification on my c++ understanding here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are implicitly convertible to a pointer to their first element.  That's why `int* location = someArray;` works.  Arrays are not themselves pointers though.

`*(++someArray)` is ill-formed because there is no `++` operator defined for arrays.  `++` is defined for pointers, but the result of the implicit conversion from array to pointer is a temporary (an rvalue), and the `++` operator is only defined for named objects (lvalues).

`*++&someArray` and `*++(&someArray)` are ill-formed, again, because the `&` operator returns an unnamed temporary pointer to the array.  Again, the `++` operator is only defined for lvalues.  Additionally, the type of `&someArray` is `int (*)[4]` (pointer to array of 4 `int`s), not `int*`.  Even for an lvalue, the `++` operator would not behave how you want on that type.

---

What would work here is to use the `+` operator instead.  `*(someArray + 1)` is perfectly well defined.  `someArray` decays to an `int*`, is shifted by one position, and that value dereferenced.  In fact, the subscript operator is defined in terms of the `+` operator.  `someArray[n]` is defined to be equivalent to `*(someArray + n)`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with all three of your last lines is that you are trying to increment a constant.

The address of `someArray` is a constant. You can't change it. You have to assign it to a pointer variable first, and then you can change the pointer.

Comment: A addition: As the (not inluded) error message should have stated the address is not an `lvalue` which means it is not an addressable object in memory but kind of "hard coded" into the programs code. The linker (i believe it was) will propably replace the object identifier from the compiler with the corresponding address of the array.